# Tez not installed, go to play store and install? on Web Payment Test Demo

Tags: javascript, html, google-pay, upi, google-tez

Is there any test cadential for google pay india.
I download the sample from https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/samples
and try to open it, but it show

> Tez not installed, go to play store and install?

What does it mean and how to solve this problem?

Comment: i am also getting same error downloaded from GIT HUB

Comment: Any answers to this yet?